# Creating subdomains in Xampp server windows

Tags: xampp, vhosts

I am trying to create sub-domains on my localhost to be accessed concurrently by my team but only the first project is loaded even when the url for the second domain is typed in the browser.

So far I have tried changing the httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@smartsacco.localhost.com
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/smartsacco/public"
      ServerName smartsacco.localhost.com
      ErrorLog "logs/smartsacco.localhost.com-error.log"
      CustomLog "logs/smartsacco.localhost.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@mfarmer.localhost.com
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Mfarmer/public"
      ServerName mfarmer.localhost.com
      ErrorLog "logs/mfarmer.localhost.com-error.log"
      CustomLog "logs/mfarmer.localhost.com-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

And also modified the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   smartsacco.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   mfarmer.localhost.com
```

Saddly only the contents of `smartsacco.localhost.com` is loaded even when I type `mfarmer.localhost.com`. What could Be wrong or and what can I do to have them both working?

Comment: Sounds like all requests are served by the first defined host, which is considered the default or fallback host by the apache http server. So most likely you have an issue with the host names in the reqests. Check the incoming request headers in your browsers console: what hostname header is specified there?

Comment: @arkascha how can I check that? I am poor at networking stuff I must confess

Comment: You open your browsers console (typically F12, but depends on operating system and browser type), in there should be a "Network" tab or similar. Perform a single request and examine that one as it is recorded: check the request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is correct, I suggest you restart Apache server and maybe the entire computer